# Calculating cutoff frequency of RCL circuit

Tags: low-pass, cutoff-frequency

Given is this circuit:

[image]

I know that:

$$G(j\omega)=\frac{\frac{1}{j\omega C}}{j\omega L+\frac{1}{j\omega C}+R}$$

But how do I calculate from this my cutoff frequency?

Comment: Rearrange it a little, to get rid of double fractions. Then...

Comment: If you are looking for the -6 dB voltage point, generically, multiply by \$\frac{j\omega C}{j\omega C}\$ to get a numerator of 1 and a new denominator. Separate out the denominator into the real (\$A\$) and imaginary (\$B\$) portions and then solve \$4=A^2+B^2\$ for the only possible value of \$\omega\$ that is real and positive.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is faster to re-derive the transfer function of this second order circuit. You will see that using the FACTs described [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371), it is truly easy. You can obtain the transfer function by 1st determining the ratio \$H_0=\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$ for \$s=0\$: short the inductor and open the capacitor. You see from the below sketch that \$H_0\$=1. This is shown in the below sketch:

[image]

You then determine the time constants of this circuit when the excitation is reduced to 0 V (replace the input source by a short circuit) and "look" at resistance offered by the energy-storing connecting terminals when alternately placed into their dc or high-frequency state: Dc state for a cap. is an open circuit but a short circuit for an inductor and a short circuit for a cap. but an open circuit for an inductor is you place them into their HF state. As shown in the sketch, you determine the time constants for \$b_1\$ by inspection only: the resistance driving \$C_1\$ is \$R_1\$ then \$\tau_1=R_1C_1\$ and for \$\tau_2\$, there is an infinite resistance "seen" from \$L_2\$'s terminals when \$C_1\$s is in its dc state: \$\tau_2=\frac{L_2}{\infty}=0\$. The first term of the second-order polynominal form is thus \$b_1=\tau_1+\tau_2=R_1C_1\$. For the second term, you now look at the resistance offered by \$L_2\$'s terminals when \$C_1\$ is set in its HF state: you "see" \$R_1\$ leading to \$\tau_{12}=\frac{L_2}{R_1}\$. This is it, the second term \$B_2\$ is equal to \$b_2=\tau_1\tau_{12}=\frac{L_2}{C_1}\$. The denominator of this transfer function is the determined as \$D(s)=1+b_1s+b_2s^2=1+sR_1C_1+s^2L_2C_1\$. You can put it under the following canonical form \$D(s)=1+\frac{s}{\omega_0Q}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2\$ in which your resonant frequency \$\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L_2C_1}}\$ and \$Q=\frac{1}{\omega_0R_1C_1}\$. The complete transfer function is thus \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_0Q}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2}\$. The below Mathcad sheet shows the dynamic response plot:

[image]

For the -3-dB crossover point, use the canonical form to determine the magnitude when \$s=j\omega\$. The result is here:

[image]

You can see how the FACTs quickly got you to the results, without writing a single line of algebra with the associated risk of making mistakes. Just a few drawings that you can individually fix in case you have a deviation between the raw expression - \$H_{ref}\$ in the Mathcad sheet - and the *low-entropy* expression. A truly useful skill that I encourage students and engineers to acquire.

Comment: One short comment: There are many cases, where the cut-off is NOT defined as -3dB magnitude drop. I am sure, you know that - but, at least, it should be mentioned.

Comment: Hallo LvW, correct, I considered a general case here for simplicity. Danke for pointing this out.